# Oracle Cursor vs. SQL Server Cursor

Tags: sql-server, oracle, cursor

I am a newbie in Oracle and I was wondering if Oracle has options for cursors like [SQLSERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).
Like this ones:

`[ LOCAL | GLOBAL ]

     [ FORWARD_ONLY | SCROLL ]

     [ STATIC | KEYSET | DYNAMIC | FAST_FORWARD ]

     [ READ_ONLY | SCROLL_LOCKS | OPTIMISTIC ]

     [ TYPE_WARNING ]

     FOR select_statement

     [ FOR UPDATE [ OF column_name [ ,...n ] ] ]`

Please post some links where I could read on how to use them or code examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Explicit cursors in Oracle don't have metadata associated with them.  The following is a translation, putting Oracle's behaviour into a T-SQL context.

Oracle cursors do not support scrolling.  So they are FORWARD_ONLY, no discussion.  This means SCROLL, FAST_FORWARD, SCROLL_LOCKS and KEYSET do not apply.

All Oracle cursors are LOCAL.

Because of Oracle's isolation level, the cursors are the equivalent of INSENSITIVE and STATIC.

Cursors are OPTIMISTIC unless we use the `FOR UPDATE` SQL syntax, which locks the selected row(s).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2130052)

Cursors are READ_ONLY.  They are for fetching data only.  We can use the `WHERE CURRENT OF` syntax to update a row identified by a cursor.  This is best used in conjunction with `FOR UPDATE`. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm#sthref3141).

You won't be surprised to learn that TYPE_WARNING doesn't apply (because nothing else does).

Comment: This is just what I wanted to know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All that info can be found [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) and specially [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/) or [HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Cursor/CURSOR-FOR-Loop.htm).

Comment: Found that link myself, but i was wondering if options like FORWARD_ONLY exist for ORACLE Cursor